# Triple delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a problem where the default delegate does not do enough in some cases.  It needs a preamble and a postable.  I'm just wondering whether it is better to call a triple delegate

```
CSELib.ELib eventLib = new CSELib.ELib();
eventLib.Bomb += BombCatcherStart;
eventLib.Bomb += eventLib.BombCatcher;
eventLib.Bomb += BombCatcherEnd;
...
eventLib.BombRaise();
```

or to call one delegate which then calls the three

```
void BombCatcherGroup(CSELib.Elib self)
{
    BombCatcherStart(self);
    self.BombCatcher(self);
    BombCatcherEnd(self);
}

CSELib.ELib eventLib = new CSELib.ELib();
eventLib.Bomb += BombCatcherGroup;
...
eventLib.BombRaise();
```

It basically does the same thing but I just wondering as far as "best practice" is concerned, whether it is better to tell everyone up front as in the triple delegate or to hide it as in in the single delegate.

Comment: What do you mean by "tell everyone up front"? And what do you mean by "the default delegate does not do enough"? Your question is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like it'll end up just being opinion-based...

Comment: As far as best practices go, i would avoid the first one. That solution is making the assumption that the events are fired sequentially in the same order as they were added. I don't think the framework has such a guarantee generally.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading into this but it really sounds like an X-Y question. I'd be much more inclined to add `BeforeBomb` (`Bombing`?) and `AfterBomb` (`Bombed`?) events and subscribe to each of these once. You have no control what else subscribes to Bomb and in what order. Honestly it's hard to tell without a complete example of what you're trying to do though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario where your operations form a logical chain there aren't really any pros to adding them as individual handlers to the same event - other than that those handlers can be removed down the track. If you don't need/want that, you're incurring the entirely avoidable (if negligible in most scenarios) overhead of additional delegate invocations and losing at least some of the ability to control execution flow. What happens if `BombCatcher` throws an exception? Easy to handle if all your operations are part of the same method definition; not so easy if you're dealing with separate delegates.